# array iterating

Tags: java, xml

I have the following xml format ,which i am parsing and getting the data and storing in an bean called xyz which has testurl as anotherbean 
xyz has testurl bean an array ,test url bean has id and image

```
<xyz>
  <testUrl Id="SmallLogo">smallLogo.jpg</testUrl > 
  <testUrl Id="MediumLogo">mediumLogo.jpg</testUrl > 
  <testUrl Id="LargeLogo">largeLogo.jpg</testUrl > 
  <testUrl Id="ExtraLarge">test.png</testUrl > 
  </xyz>
<xyz>
  <testUrl Id="SmallLogo">smallLogo.jpg</testUrl > 
  <testUrl Id="MediumLogo">mediumLogo.jpg</testUrl > 
  <testUrl Id="LargeLogo">largeLogo.jpg</testUrl > 
  <testUrl Id="ExtraLarge">test.png</testUrl > 
  </xyz>
```

i am accessing the data has `xyz.gettesturl()[i].getid()`,not able to iterate properly and get all the data,how would i iterate through the array ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sarah, that's not even valid XML; you're opening each of the child tags with `<testURL>` but closing them with `</ResourceUrl>`.  Also, you're not showing us any of the code for your class `xyz`.  (And is the bean really called "xyz", against the Java naming convention that class names are capitalized?)

Comment: its jst a sample i have posted the actual data is different,i am getting the data properly after parsing the problem is in iteration
xyz bean holds testurl[] bean which holds id and image ,how would i get the image using xyz bean?

Comment: Once again, you might want to **provide the Java code** for the `xyz` and `testurl` beans.  And I'll again strenuously suggest that you read and use the Java naming conventions; it makes it much easier for others to read your code (and to help you in communities such as this, where most others are adhering to the same conventions). http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html

Comment: -1: That is one of the worst questions I have seen on stackoverflow so far. At least formulate your question in gramatically correct English. Also, if your question is about iterating over Java Beans, why are you posting XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified sample of classes and their accessor methods from what I understood the problem to be -

Class XYZ -

```
public class XYZ {

   private TestUrl[] testUrlArray;

   public XYZ(){

      testUrlArray = new TestUrl[2];
      testUrlArray[0] = new TestUrl("ID_1");
      testUrlArray[1] = new TestUrl("ID_2");
   }

   public TestUrl getTestUrl(int i){

      return testUrlArray[i];
   }
}
```

The class TestUrl -

```
public class TestUrl {

   private String id;

   public TestUrl(String id){

      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getId(){

      return id;
   }
}
```

This is how you would get the Id for a given TestUrl bean -

```
  XYZ testXYZ = new XYZ();
  System.out.println("testXYZ 0 - " + testXYZ.getTestUrl( 0 ).getId());
  System.out.println("testXYZ 1 - " + testXYZ.getTestUrl( 1 ).getId());
```

The output on the console would be -

```
 testXYZ 0 - ID_1
 testXYZ 1 - ID_2
```

Comment: This is what i am doing.But instead of using testXYZ.getTestUrl( 0 ).getId()) i wanted a loop for iteration

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
xyz.gettesturl()[i].getid()
```

Will get the specific `testUrl` that is indexed by `i`. If you want to iterate you should try by using:

```
xyz.gettesturl()
```

To iterate over.

Comment: Show us the code, and specify exactly what you are trying to achieve. I can't guess without more detail.

Answer (score -1):

the xml you provided is not valid. you dont have a ROOT element in your xml.
if you had

```
<root>
  <xyz> 
   <testUrl Id="SmallLogo">smallLogo.jpg</testUrl >  
   <testUrl Id="MediumLogo">mediumLogo.jpg</testUrl >  
   <testUrl Id="LargeLogo">largeLogo.jpg</testUrl >  
   <testUrl Id="ExtraLarge">test.png</testUrl >  
  </xyz> 
  <xyz> 
   <testUrl Id="SmallLogo">smallLogo.jpg</testUrl >  
   <testUrl Id="MediumLogo">mediumLogo.jpg</testUrl >  
   <testUrl Id="LargeLogo">largeLogo.jpg</testUrl >  
   <testUrl Id="ExtraLarge">test.png</testUrl >  
  </xyz> 
</root>
```

then you can access all ID's though you might need another bean for root element then you can use something like: root.getxyz()[i].gettesturl()[j].getid() .

Comment: really it takes 5 secs to correct it and its clearly a typo. why the vote down?